# What is the difference between NtCreateProcess and ZwCreateProcess?

Tags: windows, winapi, createprocess, kernel-mode, ntdll

What is the difference between `NtCreateProcess` and `ZwCreateProcess`? In ntdll.dll, both `NtCreateProcess` and `ZwCreateProcess` point to exactly the same address

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In user-mode the groups of Nt and Zw APIs are identical. In kernel mode they are different. The Nt API contains the actual implementation. The Zw API uses a system-call mechanism and ensures that it is calling in kernel-mode and that there is no need to check the parameters if they contain user-mode addresses. Otherwise you could use the API from user-mode with kernel parameters which would not be good. So it is just a safety mechanism.

Comment: Does "kernel mode" also include processes running with System integrity level?

Comment: @bytecode77 no it does not

Answer (score 2):

Aside from [the already given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4761712/476371) (which I don't want to parrot), in my opinion the best answer can be found on OSR Online: [here](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm%5earticle=257.htm).

Alternatively you can read books on the Native API, such as the one from Gary Nebbett called "Windows NT/2000 Native API Reference", he devotes some space to this very question, or you can use WinDbg (pronounced as "wind-bag") yourself.