# What is the use of a process with no threads in Windows?

Tags: windows, multithreading, process

I'm reading [Windows Internals (7th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735684189), and they write about processes in Chapter 1:

> ## Processes
>
> [...] a Windows process comprises the following:
>
> - [...]
> - **At least one thread of execution** Although an "empty" process is possible, it is (mostly) not useful.

What does "mostly" mean in this context? What could a process with no threads do, and how would that be useful?

EDIT: Also, in [a 2015 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nz-vWYM-2Gw&list=PLjAuO31Rg971SFWog08EDfxRJ6WbmP-zK&index=17), Mark Russinovich says that a process has "at least one thread" (19:12). Was that a generalization?

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Comment: A process with no threads still has a virtual address space and a handle table, so you might create one as a place to hide memory and handles. Very much a [niche scenario](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200306-00/?p=103538).

Comment: for example `PssCaptureSnapshot` with `PSS_CAPTURE_VA_CLONE` create empty process (by using `ZwCreateProcessEx`)

Comment: Re, "What could a process with no threads do...?" It probably could not _do_ anything. But it could _be_ what @RaymondChen said.

Comment: @RbMm and this process snapshot would be used by another application for, say, inspecting the snapshot's memory & handles? Like a "snapshot in time Process Explorer"?

Comment: @citelao, a process snapshot uses a clone (threadless fork) of the process if the VM is captured. IIRC, a clone isn't created for a snapshot of just the handle table. The executive already provides a query to capture the handle table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer has come out in the comments. There seem to be at least two scenarios where a threadless process would be useful.

### Scenario 1: capturing process snapshots

This is probably the most straightforward one. As RbMm commented, `PssCaptureSnapshot` can be called with the `PSS_CAPTURE_VA_CLONE` option to create a threadless (or "empty") process (using `ZwCreateProcessEx`, presumably to [duplicate the target process's memory in kernel mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115558/what-is-the-difference-between-ntcreateprocess-and-zwcreateprocess)).

The primary use here would be for debugging, if a developer wanted to inspect a process's memory at a certain point in time.

Notably, Eryk Sun points out that an empty process is not necessary for inspecting handles (even though an empty process holds both its own memory space *and* handles), since there is already a way to inspect a process's handles without creating a new process or duplicating memory.

### Scenario 2: forking processes with specific inherited handles---safely

Raymond Chen explains another use for a threadless process: creating new "real" processes with inherited handles safely.

When a thread wants to create a new process (`CreateProcess`), there are several ways for it to pass handles to the new process:

- Make a handle inheritable and `CreateProcess` with `bInheritHandles = true`.
- Make a handle inheritable, add it to a `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST`, and pass that list to the `CreateProcess` call.

However, they offer conflicting guarantees that can cause problems when callers want to create two threads *with different handles* concurrently. As Raymond puts it in [Why do people take a lock around CreateProcess calls?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200306-00/?p=103538):

> In order for a handle to be inherited, you not only have to put it in the `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST`, but you also must make the handle inheritable. This means that if another thread is not on board with the `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST` trick and does a straight `Create­Process` with `bInheritHandles = true`, it will inadvertently inherit your handles.

You can use a threadless process to mitigate this. In general:

1. Create a threadless process.
2. `DuplicateHandle` all of the handles you want to capture into this new threadless process.
3. `CreateProcess` your new, real forked process, using the `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST`, but set the nominal parent process of this process to be the threadless process (with `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS`).

You can now `CreateProcess` concurrently without worrying about other callers, and you can now close the duplicate handles and the empty process.